# as.Date return NA for single digit days

Tags: r, as.date

I am converting my string date to date formatted as dd-mm-yy using the as.Date function but this only work for double digit days, while returning NA for single digit day. Would somebody have any ideas why is this? Thanks
example:

```
a<-"9112015"
a.converted<-as.Date.character(a,"%d%m%Y")
```

-->returns NA

```
a<-"19112015"
a.converted<-as.Date.character(a,"%d%m%Y")
```

---> works just fine

Comment: `a[nchar(a) == 7] <- paste0('0', a[nchar(a) == 7])`, though that assumes the missing digit is from the day, not the month. Adding some delimiting characters would be helpful.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly. Thanks